# Select only one node to be processed

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm noobie when it comes to programming with xpath or xslt. Im trying to select only specified node to be processed and in the process create folders for each element. Here's my test xml im working with:

XML:

```
<Sandbox>
  <Unknow name="Unknow">
    <Property name="unknow" value="unknow"/>
  </Unknow>
  <View name="Object">
    <Element name="first" value="1">
        <Property name="great" value="10"/>
        <Element name="detail" value="3">
            <Property name="shiny" value="30"/>
            <Element name="doNot" value="0">
                <Property name="non" value="0"/>
            </Element>
        </Element>
    </Element>
</View>
<View name="OtherObject">
    <Element name="second" value="2">
        <Property name="greater" value="20"/>
        <Element name="detail" value="4">
            <Property name="dark" value="40"/>
            <Element name="doNot" value="0">
                <Property name="non" value="0"/>
            </Element>
        </Element>
    </Element>
  </View>
</Sandbox>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Sandbox/View[@name='OtherObject']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Element"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Element">
    <xsl:result-document href="{string-join(ancestor-or-self::Element,'/')}/{concat(@name,'_',position())}.xml">
        <item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </item>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

The output i want to have is a folder structure /Object/first/detail. What am i doing wrong? I'm getting an error that i cannot create output file. Do you have any advice on xpath cuz im guessing that my xpath doesnt do i right. Thanks

Comment: Your path doesn't include "doNot"(one of the elements' @name). Would you like it excluded? Also, your first template has "OtherObject" as @name.. but the folder path you want has "Object". Which node do you actually want processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
<xsl:template match="Sandbox/View[@name='OtherObject']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Element"/>
</xsl:template>
```

you probably want

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Sandbox/View[@name='OtherObject']//Element"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As for the `<xsl:result-document href="{string-join(ancestor-or-self::Element,'/')}/{concat(@name,'_',position())}.xml">`, please post the exact error message and tell us which folder names and which file names you want to construct.

```
<xsl:result-document href="{string-join(ancestor-or-self::Element,'/')}/{concat(@name,'_',position())}.xml">
```

Comment: Do you think that ist posible to save the `href` to an variable ?